# How to use tempdata to return error message

Tags: .net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to use temp data to return messages but it gives an error :

> InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.TempDataSerializer' cannot serialize an object of type

I am already using

```
        services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider(); 

        app.UseSession()

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        });
```

Here is my shared

> FlashMessages.cshtml :

```
@using EnduroMotors.ViewModels
@{
var errorMessages = TempData["_error_messages"] as List<FlashMessageModel> 
?? new List<FlashMessageModel>();
var warningMessages = TempData["_warning_messages"] as 
List<FlashMessageModel> ?? new List<FlashMessageModel>();
var successMessages = TempData["_success_messages"] as 
List<FlashMessageModel> ?? new List<FlashMessageModel>();
var infoMessages = TempData["_info_messages"] as List<FlashMessageModel> ?? 
new List<FlashMessageModel>();
}
```

Here is my viewmodel :

> FlashMessageModel

```
public class FlashMessageModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

And here is use in controller :

> Controller

```
    protected void ShowSuccessMessage(string message, string title = 
    "Success!")
    {
        var messages = 
    (List<FlashMessageModel>)TempData["_success_messages"] ?? new 
    List<FlashMessageModel>();
        messages.Add(new FlashMessageModel
        {
            Title = title,
            Message = message
        });
        TempData["_success_messages"] = messages;
    }
```

> using this with return

```
    ShowSuccessMessage("You have completed.");
```

it should show success message in index with  `@{Html.RenderPartial("FlashMessages");}` but instead it gives

InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.TempDataSerializer' cannot serialize an object of type 'EnduroMotors.ViewModels.FlashMessageModel'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.TempDataSerializer.EnsureObjectCanBeSerialized(object item)

Answer (score 1):

TempData serialises objects to strings for storage. It supports string, int and boolean types natively. If you want to store more complex types, you have to serialise (and deserialise) them yourself. JSON is the recommended format.  The following extension methods use the JSON.NET `JsonConvert` static methods to do this:

```
public static class TempDataExtensions
{
    public static void Set<T>(this ITempDataDictionary tempData, string key, T value) where T : class
    {
        tempData[key] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
    }
    public static T Get<T>(this ITempDataDictionary tempData, string key) where T : class
    {
        tempData.TryGetValue(key, out object o);
        return o ?? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>((string)o);
    }
}
```

You can read more about this here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tempdata#limitations

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'T'